# What's wrong with this convergence method for $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^c}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

> What's wrong with this convergence method for $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^c}$:

What I did was apply the criteria of

> If $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges

By doing this: $$\sum |\frac{(-1)^n}{n^c}|$$ and then since $|(-1)^n|=1$ and $n^c$ will be always positive in this case: $$=\sum \frac{1}{n^c}$$ and since this is the well known series, which converges if $c>1$, then $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^c}$ will as well converge if $c>1$, but apparently it does converge with $c>0$ and not $c>1$, what have I done wrong?

**Note: I do know how I would get to the solution $c>0$ with the limit convergence test, but I want to know what is wrong here**

Comment: You did nothing wrong:  your series is absolutely convergent iff $c>1,$ and if so, it is ipso facto convergent. This doesn't contradict the fact that for $0<c\le1,$ it is (non absolutely) convergent. Btw, what exactly do you call "get the solution $c>0$"?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. If you have a series depending on a parameter, applying a certain criterion won't necessarily give you the largest interval for that parameter so that the series converges. In this case, the absolute value requires $c>1$, but since you're considering a series bouncing between positive and negative values, you can expect to have a larger set of values for $c$ with converging series.

Comment: @Alessandro okay, wow that looks new to me, in an exam I would've just said it to be finished, is there any way I can be sure that the answer I get of a problem with a parameter like this one, is the one that covers all the correct parameters? Or do I just have to have the eye open and try with c=1 or any other values of c to be sure it's correct?

Comment: @AnneBauval okay thanks. And what I mean is that by doing the limit convergence test you get the solution $c>0$, that's all, I just didn't want someone to go and post an alternative solution to mine, only wanted to know why mine was incomplete/wrong

Comment: I did my best to answer you but I feel there is another zone of shadow. Could you please type how you "do the limit convergence test and you get the solution $c>0$"?

Answer (score 1):

Convergence of $\sum_{}^{}|a_n|$ is sufficient for convergence of $\sum_{}^{}a_n$ but not necessary.
In a conditional statement $p \implies q $ you go from left to right but not vise versa unless if it is biconditional.

For example: $x>0 \implies |x|>0$ is true but $|x|>0 \implies x>0$ is not always true. So for the same reason you can't move backward in your conclusion.